# Binary tree delete

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am trying to finish the delete function

Here is the pseudo code, notice the end.

I don't know if the pseudo code is wrong though.

Here is how I interpreted it:

```
Node* minNode = Minimum(toDelete->right);

            int tmp = 0;
            tmp = minNode->val;
            // delete(&tmp);
            free(minNode);
            minNode=NULL;
            toDelete->val=tmp;
```

Except once it deletes it, it starts filling a trillion zeroes when printing.

Is what I am doing make any sense?
The rest of the code I have is right, or I think so anyway. It only screws up in this scenario.

Here's the minimum function as well

```
Node* BST::Minimum(Node *curr) {

    // if (curr->left != NULL) {
    //      return(Minimum(curr->left));
    //  }
    //  return curr;
    Node* node = curr;
    while (node->left != NULL) {
        node = node->left;
    }
    return node;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tree delete node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822032/tree-delete-node)

Answer (score 0):

You want to first of all search the tree so see if the node you want to delete is there.

if it is there, you want to check for three casing:

1: when you want to delete a Node that have no child.
 :  in this case you just delete the said node as it does not have any child.

2: when you want to delete a node that has either left of right child 
  : in this case you set the left or right child to the parent of the node you want to delete

3: when you want to delete a node with two children
 : in this case you have to find the successor of the node you are to delete, then swap the successor with the delete node.

```
public Boolean delete(int key)
{
    Node current = root;
    Node parent = root;

     //search for node here
    while(current->key != key)
    {
       parent = current; //save the parent the nodes as you loop through it
       if(key < current->key)
           current = current->left
       else
            current = current->right

        //if you do not find the key return false
        if(current==null)
           return false;
    }
    //case 1 start here:
    //check if the said node has no child. in this case we are looking at current
    if(current->left ==null && current->right == null)
     {
          //check if the node you want to delete is the root
          if(current == root)
            root = current
          else
             {
                 if(parent.key > current->key)
                     parent-left = null;
                 else
                     parent->right = null;
             }
     }//case 2 here:
      //check to see if the node has either left or right child
           else if(statement for checking left here)
           {
           //check for the case where your delete a root

           //set the the parent of the current->left to be current->parent
           }
          else if(statement for checking right here)
          {

           //check for the case where your delete a root

           //set the the parent of the current->right to be current->parent
          }
     else
        {
             //create a node successor and give it the successor you found
             Node successor = findSuccessor(Node NodeToDel);

             //check for root being the node you want to delete

             if(root == successor)
                root =  successor;
             else
                {
                    //navigate left, set parent->left = successor

                    //navigate right, set parent->right = successor

                    //with the nature of the findSuccessor() algorithm i have,
                    //i will have to code one more line:

                    // give succeccor->left = current->left; 
                }


        }

     }
```

I hope this will help in some way.